# bash syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".google.com") when parsing through array

Tags: bash, text-processing, grep, array

I have an array of domains that I am attempting to iterate through and check if a string from a file matches any of the domains in the array. However, when the for loop starts, I get an error

```
line 64: www.google.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".google.com")
```

the array and for loop look like this:

```
sites=("www.google.com" "www.bing.com" "www.yahoo.com" "www.duckduckgo.com")

while read line; do
    csvString=$(echo "$line");
    greppedDomain=$(echo "$line" | grep -Eo '[A-Za-z0-9]{2,62}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,62}\.[A-Za-z]{2,62}'); 
    for i in "${sites[@]}"; do
        if [ "$greppedDomain" = "${sites[$i]}" ]
        then
            sitesOut+=($csvString);
        fi
    done
done < sitelist.txt
```

I am currently at a loss, maybe it is an issue with the way the grep output stores in the variable?

Comment: As mentioned in a now-deleted answer, `csvString=($echo "$line")` is wrong. You have no variable called `echo`. You just want `csvString=$line` since you're not using the `csvString` variable as an array. But you might as well use `read csvString` directly.

Comment: There are a few other issues. Paste your code into http://shellcheck.net for tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a string element of the array as the numeric index:

```
for i in "${sites[@]}"; do
    if [ "$greppedDomain" = "${sites[$i]}" ]
```

In a numerically indexed array, when dereferencing, the index part in square brackets is actually an arithmetic expression. That allows you to do index arithmetic like `x[i]=${x[i+1]}` for example.

To reproduce the error:

```
$ x=(a b c)
$ i="www.google.com"
$ echo "${x[i]}"
bash: www.google.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".google.com")
```

To demonstrate the arithmetic nature of the array index, let's look at the string in an arithmetic expression:

```
$ echo $((www.google.com))
bash: www.google.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".google.com")
```

Same error.

The error token is ".google.com" -- why is that?

1. when parsing `$((www.google.com))` the `www` part will be taken as a *shell variable*.

   - In an arithmetic expression, variables do not need to be prefixed with a dollar sign
   - test: `a=5; b=7; echo $(( a * b ))`
2. but, arithmetically, there is no `.` operator, so the parser does not know what to do with the rest of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

There are two standardish ways to iterate over an array in bash. One option is to loop over the element values directly. This will run the loop with `elem` set to "www.google.com", then with "www.bing.com", etc:

```
sites=("www.google.com" "www.bing.com" "www.yahoo.com" "www.duckduckgo.com")
for elem in "${sites[@]}"; do
    echo "The element is: $elem"
done
```

The other option is to loop over the array *indexes*, that is, 0, 1, 2, etc (where `${sites[0]}` is "www.google.com", `${sites[1]}` is "www.bing.com", etc):

```
for i in "${!sites[@]}"; do    # The ! makes it list indexes, rather than elements
    echo "The $i'th element is: ${sites[i]}"
done
```

The problem here is that you've mixed these methods, looping over the element values, but then treating them as indexes.

Some other problems:

```
csvString=($echo "$line");
```

In the first place, the `($` should be `$(`, and in the second place you shouldn't use `$(echo ...)` -- the `echo` and the `$( )` mostly cancel each other out (except for some possible parsing oddities you probably don't want). Just use this:

```
csvString=$line
```

BTW, notice that I didn't put a semicolon at the end? In the shell, you don't need semicolons at the ends of lines in shell (except some odd cases like the double-semicolon that ends `case` options). You only need them if you're putting multiple command-like things on the same line. For instance, this:

```
if somethingorother; then
    echo "this"; echo "that"
fi
```

Could be equivalently written:

```
if somethingorother
then
    echo "this"
    echo "that"
fi
```